# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty (using nested_forms + carrier wave)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

In short I have a User model and a Photo model, the user has a profile page and I'd like to allow the user to upload various photos to their profile using carrier wave and nested_forms.

I'm using Devise for the User model. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've been fooling around with this all day, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Thanks in advanced!**

Error:

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

<%= nested_form_for @user, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photos| %>
```

form code in user_profile.html.erb:

```
<%= nested_form_for @user, :html=>{:multipart => true } do |f| %>                                                                           
   <%= f.error_messages %>                                                                                                                   
   <%= f.fields_for :photos do |p|  %>                                                                                                  
   <p>                                                                                                                                       
   <%= p.label :photo %><br />                                                                                                          
   <%= p.file_field :photo %>                                                                                                           
   </p>                                                                                                                                      
   <%= p.link_to_remove "Remove this photo" %>                                                                            
   <% end %>                                                                                                                                 
   <%= f.link_to_add "Add attachment", :photos %>                                                                                            
   <p><%= f.submit %></p>                                                                                                                    
 <% end %>
```

Note: bare in mind the user_profile page is backed by devise, i.e. up to this point all of the form_for stuff has been in the edit.html.erb page. That may or may have to do with the error but let's carry on.

User.rb snippit:

```
has_many :photos, as: :index_photos_on_user_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

  mount_uploader :profile_image, ProfileImageUploader
```

Photo.rb

```
class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :photo, :user_id

  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

  belongs_to :user, :polymorphic => true

end
```

Schema:

```
create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "photo"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

add_index "photos", ["user_id"], name: "index_photos_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
 .... the rest here
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  private

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if user_signed_in?
      welcome_path
    else
      new_user_registration_path
    end
  end


end
```

registrations_controller.rb

```
 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # POST /resource                                                                                                                                            

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def update
    # For Rails 4                                                                                                                                             
    # account_update_params = devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)                                                                            
    # For Rails 3                                                                                                                                             
    account_update_params = params[:user]

    # required for settings form to submit when password is left blank                                                                                        
    if account_update_params[:password].blank?
      account_update_params.delete("password")
      account_update_params.delete("password_confirmation")
    end

    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(account_update_params)
      set_flash_message :notice, :updated
      # Sign in the user bypassing validation in case his password changed                                                                                    
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to after_update_path_for(@user)
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def account_registration
     @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end
```

routes.rb snippit

```
devise_scope :user do
  #  get "edit/edit_account", :to => "devise/registrations#edit_account", :as => "account_registration"                                                       
    get 'edit/edit_account' => 'users/registrations#account_registration', as: :edit_account
    get '/welcome' => 'home#landing_welcome', as: :welcome
  end
```

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, this has been a battle! I've updated the post with the controller.

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: that's weird, add puts statements to both `new` methods on your controller to see if they're being called

Comment: It doesn't look like they're being called.. do you use team viewer? that might be easier.

Comment: You showed us user_profile.html.erb view, but none of your controller is rendering this view. Could you: a) show the code rendering this template 2) ensure that @user is being set in relevant controller action.

Comment: Ah that's a great point, I just tried changing the new action to a user_profile action but still no the same error?

Comment: Quick debug advice: add `raise 'whatever'` to your controller action and check whether it was raised or not.

Comment: Alright, check this out - we're getting closer.. I've just realized that the user_profile isn't even a part of the devise controller but a part of the home_controller, so when I added @user = User.new to the user_action method in the home_controller I'm now getting undefined method `users_path' how do I sync this controller with the devise one? as it's currently inheriting from application con

Comment: I am not really sure whether you want to create a new user whan someone visit your home page. :) But anyway... In general you want to add `before_filter :authenticate_user!`. You should read this if you didn't already: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise. The error you're getting is routing problem, try running `rake routes` and see what's the problem there.

Comment: Thanks BroiStatse, Correct I don't want to create a new user when someone  visits the home page, but rather find the user that is visiting the home page which is the profile. I've added my updated devise scope route but now when I use @user = User.find(params[:id]) it's saying Couldn't find user without an ID.

Comment: Make sure @ user is set and pass a :URL argument to the form_for so it doesn't introspect @ user to generate the form action. If the user is not logged in then set @ user to current_user otherwise User.new.

Comment: Thanks davidfurber, that is the best answer yet can you please write that out as an answer including the proper URL argument and I will accept it!

Answer (score 0):

You `resource` method is nil or empty. So, you have define resource.

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
module ApplicationHelper

  ## Devise helper method for resource
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
......
end
```

And include this ApplicationHelper module in custom controller

```
#app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  include ApplicationHelper
.........
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution, because it assumes resource will be a new User no matter where it is called. So this may fix a specific problem, but may well cause unexpected results as the application is developed.